How to enforce getting a struct ref reference from a class to avoid copies?
I have several members on a class that are structs.
Even if I create a property that returns ref, people usually forget it's a struct and get it without using ref, so they make a copy.
How can I enforce people to use ref when they get the variables to avoid future bugs?.
The naming of the variables can't be changed, it's not my personal project, so when the name is not clear enough (like   DrawingManager, for example), people doesn't know it's a struct.

I think this should be the job for an analyzer, but I'm not sure if rosyln has a ready-made one.

You can't, just because it's completely fine to just use the de-referenced value instead:
ref int GetArrayReference(int[] items, int index) => ref items[index];

void IncrementInsideArrayByRef()
{
    int[] values = { 1, 2, 3 };

    var item = GetArrayReference(values, 1);
    IncrementByRef(ref item);
    // what does this line print, and why?
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", values));
}

void IncrementByRef(ref int i) => i = i + 1;

In the above case GetArrayReference will return the reference of a specific item in the array. However we don't use ref here, which means "use the value directly". So instead of printing 1,3,3, this code will print 1,2,3, because the original item was unchanged. It's completely okay to just use the value of the returned reference.
In other words: when you want a reference, use the ref-keyword, when you want a value, just omit the keyword.
You could indicate the type being returned using some naming-convention, e.g. appending Reference to the function as in the previous example. However as you've stated you cannot change the naming, that's not an option for you.
After all my gut feeling it, that at least a DrawManager should never be a value-type in the first place as it is unlikely that it represents a "small data-centric type that provide[s] little or no behavior" as mentioned in the docs about structs in C#

He already know how to use ref he just want to force the user to keep the same instance which is in the ref. The question is not How to use ref keyword?

@Kaiwinta well, the simple answer is: it's not possible - as seen in my very first sentence. I just wrote why it is not possible.

Okay perfekt, sorry for missunderstanding, it's just that I was thinking of something like user27314112 answer

It depends on how your code is structured. How are the struct members exposed? Are they public? You could encapsulate them by making the struct members private and the method public. Then, by returning ref from the method, you can ensure that no copies are made.
It could look something like this:
public class MyClass
{
  private MyStruct _myStruct;

  public ref MyStruct GetMyStruct()
  {
    return ref _myStruct;
  }
}

Again this is just how I understood your problem. Another solution might be better depending on your case since you have claimed it's not your personal project.

Yes. That's what I have. Properties that return ref. But if somebody does:
a = MyClass.MyStruct    then it's a copy.
So my question is. HOW to enforce and make people very aware of it?  Because the name is not  "MyStruct" , it's   DrawingManager... but it's a struct

@Darkgaze - Please edit your question and add all relevant details, such as code inside of it.

@Darkgaze i mean technically MyStruct is just a placeholder. You can name it Drawingmanager it makes no difference. With setting it private and the GetMethod being public you can only access the method itself. I have the strong feeling that I don't fully understand the IS and SHOULD state. Other ways are quite tricky you could add comments making the dev aware but its no way of enforcing. The way i posted above is the only way I know of enforcing something that is not yours. Some code would be very beneficial
